# Display Product related to PriceBook in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lookup, pricebook, lookup-filter, product

I have a custom object `Product Quantity` and it has lookup to `Product2`, I've created a `Visualforce Page` for Quote Creation (`Quote` standard object), and the `Quote` object has lookup field to `Price Book`.

Now, my question is:

How can I only display Products in the lookup search which are related to the `Quote` record's `Price Book`? Would a `Lookup Filter` work for this scenario?

I am asking this because I tried to put lookup filter in custom field product in the custom object but I am not able to select Quote's Price Book there.